# Creating a `va_list` Using a Pointer of Packed Arguments on Clang and g++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I am working on a cycle-accurate simulator for a research architecture.  I already have a cross-compiler that generates assembly (based on MIPS).  For debug purposes, we have a `printf` intrinsic which ultimately, when run in the simulator, calls a builtin method that has access to a list of arguments packed in a contiguous array (such as would be created by this code):

```
template <typename type> inline static void insert(char buffer[], size_t* i, type value) {
    memcpy(buffer+*i,&value, sizeof(type)); *i+=sizeof(type);
}
int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    char buffer[512]; size_t i=0;
    insert<double>(buffer,&i, 3.14);
    insert<int>(buffer,&i, 12345);
    insert<char const*>(buffer,&i, "Hello world!");

    return 0;
}
```

In MSVC, one can then create a `va_list` and call `vprintf` like so:

```
union { va_list list; char* arguments; } un;
un.arguments = buffer;
vprintf(format_string, un.list);
```

The target architecture is x86-64, which is based on x86, so this produces apparently correct results (the `va_list` provided by MSVC is just a typedef for `char*`).

However, on g++ (and presumably Clang; I haven't tried), the code segfaults.  This happens because the underlying type (it's compiler-provided: in gcc 4.9.2, it appears to be typedefed from `__gnuc_va_list`, which is in turn typedefed from `__builtin_va_list`, presumably a compiler intrinsic) is different (as the compiler error you get it you just go `un.list=buffer;` forbodes).

---

My question is: what is the cleanest way to convert this array of packed arguments into a `va_list` *that is usable by both g++ and Clang in x86-64 mode*?

My current thinking is that it may be better to parse out each format specifier individually, then forward it off with the appropriate argument to `printf`.  This isn't as robust (in the sense of supporting all features of `printf`; working on a single architecture only is robust enough for our purposes), nor is it particularly compelling, though.

Comment: I'm guessing an argument limit (to the number of args), together with exponential code generation in the limit, wouldn't be good enough?  :)  How about one that extracts one formatter at a time, then forwards the formatting to a single-argument call to a type-safe `printf`?

Answer (score 1):

For a baseline answer, here is some simple code (reasonably well tested, but no guarantees) that implements the parse-the-format-string method I mentioned.  I release it into the public domain.

If someone writes an answer that actually solves the problem I asked (doing this, but using `va_list`; i.e., a much cleaner solution) then I will accept that answer instead.

```
static void printf_buffer(char const*__restrict format_string, char*__restrict argument_buffer) {
    int num_chars = 0;
    PARSE_CHAR:
        switch (*format_string) {
            case '\0': return;
            case '%': {
                int i = 1;
                char c;
                PARSE_SPECIFIER:
                    c = format_string[i++];
                    switch (c) {
                        case 'd': case 'i':
                        case 'u': case 'o': case 'x': case 'X':
                        case 'f': case 'F': case 'e': case 'E': case 'g': case 'G': case 'a': case 'A':
                        case 'c': case 's': case 'p':
                            goto PRINT_SPECIFIER;
                        case 'n':
                            assert(i==2,"\"%%n\" must contain no intermediary characters!");
                            **reinterpret_cast<int**>(argument_buffer) = num_chars;
                            argument_buffer += sizeof(int*);
                            goto DONE_SPECIFIER;
                        case '%':
                            assert(i==2,"\"%%%%\" must contain no intermediary characters!");
                            putchar('%'); ++num_chars;
                            goto DONE_SPECIFIER;
                        case '\0': assert(false,"Expected specifier before end of string!");
                        default: goto PARSE_SPECIFIER;
                    }
                PRINT_SPECIFIER: {
                    char* temp = new char[i+1];
                    strncpy(temp,format_string,i); temp[i]='\0';
                    #define PRINTBRK(TYPE) num_chars+=printf(temp,*reinterpret_cast<TYPE*>(argument_buffer)); argument_buffer+=sizeof(TYPE); break;
                    switch (c) {
                        case 'd': case 'i': PRINTBRK(int)
                        case 'u': case 'o': case 'x': case 'X': PRINTBRK(unsigned int)
                        case 'f': case 'F': case 'e': case 'E': case 'g': case 'G': case 'a': case 'A': PRINTBRK(double)
                        case 'c': PRINTBRK(char)
                        case 's': PRINTBRK(char const*)
                        case 'p': PRINTBRK(void*)
                        default: assert(false,"Implementation error!");
                    }
                    #undef PRINTBRK
                    delete [] temp;
                }
                DONE_SPECIFIER:
                    format_string += i;
                    break;
            }
            default:
                putchar(*format_string); ++format_string; ++num_chars;
                break;
        }
        goto PARSE_CHAR;
}
```

Here is a link to the full source, including an enclosing test: [link](http://pastebin.com/NTJ7Mav0).  Expected output:

```
double: 3.1400, float: +3.1400, getting characters: ->, percent: %, int:      12345, string: "Hello world!"
Printed 54 characters before the marked point:
                                                      <-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct buffer {
  const char* ptr = 0;
  size_t count = 0;
};
template<class T>
T const* get_arg( buffer& b ) {
  T const* r = reinterpret_cast<T const*>(b.ptr);
  b.ptr += sizeof(T);
  b.count -= sizeof(T);
  return r;
}
template<class...Ts, size_t...Is>
void print( const char* format, std::index_sequence<Is...>, buffer& b ) {
  std::tuple<Ts const*...> tup;
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(
    std::get<Is>(tup) = get_arg<Ts>(b)
  ,void(),0)...};
  printf( format, (*std::get<Is>(tup))... );
}
template<class...Ts>
void print( const char* format, buffer& b ) {
  print(format, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, b)
}
```

The above, given a bundle of types `<Ts...>` and a `buffer`, will call `printf( format, ts... )` where `ts...` are the data extracted from the `buffer`.

The next step is to extract the `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier` format commands one at a time.  Take a substring containing only one of these commands, and feed it to the above.

Count how many `*` entries are in there, and based off that number ask for that many `int`s.

Finally, the length and specifier are mapped to a C++ type.

The technique required to map runtime values to compile time indexes (or C++ types) can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430249/optimize-template-replacement-of-a-switch) among other spots.

This has the downside that upwards of 150 functions get generated.

As a side benefit, you can actually check that your buffer has enough data, and throw or exit if you run out instead of reading bad memory.