# Parameter pack expansion with lambda

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to instantiate a function table (to emulate `switch`)

```
  template<size_t ... N>
  int f(std::index_sequence<N...>, int k)
  {
    static auto f_table = { []() { return N; }... };
    auto f = f_table.begin() + k;
    assert((*f)() == k);
    return (*f)();
  }
```

which fails with `error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:`

I can get by with an extra wrapper function but why does lambda fail and is there a workaround?

Comment: GCC? Ancient? https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64488

Comment: g++ 5.4 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Comment: This [works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CTXf0P) in new GCC with minor modifications.

Comment: That's ancient.

Comment: well ok, compiler bug then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752568/expanding-parameter-pack-into-lambda-with-fold-expression-gcc-vs-clang had it in 7.0

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: …Because the lambdas have different types otherwise, if that’s not obvious to everyone.

Comment: you need at least G++ 8.1 to make this work. could look into using a different ppa, or build from source. Too bad JonathonF took his ppa's offline.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug that [GCC doesn't expand template parameter pack that appears in a lambda-expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226), which was fixed in GCC 8 eventually.

The other issue with the code as also mentioned in the comments is that every lambda in the list `{ []() { return N; }... }` has its own distinct type, so one has to convert them into function pointers with `+` operator first:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

template<std::size_t ... N>
int f(std::index_sequence<N...>, std::size_t k) {
   static auto f_table = { +[]() { return N; }... };
   auto f = f_table.begin() + k;
   assert((*f)() == k);
   return (*f)();
}

int main() {
    f(std::make_index_sequence<3>{}, 2);
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jWrfn7d6W